# Wordpress wp_enqueue_scripts() triggers 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm editing a `functions.php` file in a child version of a WordPress theme in order to load a custom javascript `filmScript.js`, which exists, but is currently empty. If I comment out line 10

```
wp_enqueue_scripts( 'myVideo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/filmScript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
```

everything works: echo statements log to the console, the page loads, etc. However, when the line is being read the page breaks and throws a `500 Internal Server Error`. Here's the entire functions.php:

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'video_bg', 10);
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'post_theme_setup' );

if ( !function_exists( 'post_theme_setup' )):
function post_theme_setup(){

    function video_bg() {
        wp_enqueue_scripts( 'myVideo', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/filmScript.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false );
        echo '<script>console.log("Script added?")</script>';
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'video_bg', 10);
    echo '<script>console.log("Action added")</script>';

}
endif;
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: What's the actual error? Check your log.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be echoing anything at this stage. That's why you enqueue the scripts instead of simply outputting them directly. Try commenting out the `echo` statements.

Comment: function inside function and enqueue one script twice,this is the problem. write your code properly!

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'm pretty new to php, so it's a bit of a learning curve. Here's the thing: Internal Server Error is only thrown in the browser, where I'm logged in to my WordPress admin (Chrome). In Firefox or Chrome Incognito mode the page loads, but the script isn't added. In a Chrome instance where I'm logged in the error is the following: `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas16_data03/79/3673879/html/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3744`

Answer (score 1):

Please use `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`. It can't work in enqueue scripts because it's for enqueueing stylesheets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I've changed it to get_template_directory_uri(), but the problem still persists. Please, refer to my latest comment above about the `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/content/p3pnexwpnas16_data03/79/3673879/html/wp-includ‌​es/formatting.php on line 3744`

Comment: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes` (Place this at the top of your PHP script and let your script loose!)